# How to show that f is identically constant

Tags: analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous partial differentiable, such that:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=0$$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$

I need help to show that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Hint: Mean Value Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just solve the equation for $f(x, y)$:
$$
f_x = 0 \implies f = A + g(y) \implies f_y = g'(y) = 0 \implies g = B \implies f = A + B = C = \text{const}
$$

Comment: Some more words and less misuse of symbols would help here.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff which symbols are misused, if I may ask? Did you mean that I omitted some arguments?

Answer (score 3):

It suffices to show that for every real numbers $h,k$ we have $f(h,k)=f(0,0)$. I will  that $f(h,0)=f(h,k)$ for any choice of $k$, and leave to you to show that $f(h,0)=f(0,0)$ for any choice of $h$.

Fix a real number $h$. Note that the function $g(s) = f(h,s)$ is such that $g'$ is identically zero by hypothesis. For any choice of real number $k$ there is $\xi\in [0,k]$ such that

$$g(k)-g(0) = g'(\xi)k=0$$

so that $g(0)=f(h,0)=g(k)=f(h,k)$, and this proves what was claimed.